# How do I open two files and subtract them then store them into a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to ask how do I open two files with data inside and subtract them then store them into a file ?

```
     with open("bignum.txt","r") as f:
                score=f.read()
                score_ints =[int(x) for x in score.split()]

        with open("smallnum.txt","r")as d:
            score_y = d.read()
            score_y_ints =[int(x) for x in score_y.split()]
        difference = [x - y for x, y in zip(score_ints, score_y_ints) ]
```

smallnum.txt
10000
120

bignum.txt
99
2220

Expected outcome :
9901
-2100

so this is my previous code . It will output it as list but this isn't what I wanted.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the text files and what is your expected output

Comment: @Tzane I ve attached the outcome on my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("f1.txt", "r") as f:
    f1 = f.read()
    f1_ints = [int(x) for x in f1.split()]


with open("f2.txt", "r") as f:
    f2 = f.read()
    f2_ints = [int(x) for x in f2.split()]
    
with open("f1_minus_f2.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in range( min( len(f1_ints), len(f2_ints)) ) : 
        f.write(str(f1_ints[i] - f2_ints[i]))
        f.write(' ')
```